# Google Spreadsheet - Sum cell value if another cell contain one of N strings

Tags: excel, google-sheets, excel-formula

As shown on this [Google Spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/140vuDU-7y0fKhL9ZAoOsbUJSvx8EqeJKE4iyM5u--y4/edit?usp=sharing) I would like to **SUM** a list of currency values from a column only if in the row of the value I have one of the selected strings from a list.

```
| Tag    | Value |
| :      |     : |
| Goo    |   12$ | <= SUM value because I have Goo or Boo
| Dee    |    3$ |
| Boo    |    4$ | <= SUM value because I have Goo or Boo
| Yoo    |    7$ |
| :      |     : |
| Result |   16$ |
```

I didn't found a way to do that, is that possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can just sum two `SUMIF()` functions together.

```
=SUMIF(A:A,"Goo",B:B) + SUMIF(A:A,"Boo",B:B)
```

Assuming that `A:A` contains the words to match and `B:B` contains the values to sum.

To be more specific to your issue, you will actually have to modify your range so you are not getting any circular reference errors (since the cell is in the same column as your sum range)

So, if the cell that contains your formula is in row 25 (for example), then something like this should work:

```
=SUMIF(A1:A24,"Goo",B1:B24) + SUMIF(A1:A24,"Boo",B1:B24)
```

Comment: It was pretty simple!

Answer (score 2):

[image]

`=ArrayFormula(SUMPRODUCT((A2:A5=({"Goo","Boo"}))*(B2:B5)))` - `SUMIF` has a lot of inherent limitations, you would do well to read something about array formulas.